# winsock2 accepting clients without calling accept function

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, winsock2

I'm trying winsock example from Microsoft docs,

**client code**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-client-code

**server code**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-server-code

Problem I'm facing is **connect** function in client code returns valid socket fd without accepting from server side, I removed the **accept** function but client still able to connect and return valid socket fd.

```
iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

while (1)
{
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `listen()` returns success, the OS will accept requests for new connections for you in the background and put the new connections into an internal queue, which `accept()` will then pull from.  So, even if the server code never calls `accept()`, new connections will still be accepted in the background as long as the queue is not full.  If the queue does fill up, subsequent requests for new connections will fail with a `(WSA)ECONNREFUSED` error.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer its really helpful, is it possible to check if server accepted from client side or accept connections  only with `accept()` function ?

Comment: There is no way to disable the queue handling on the server side, and the closest way the client can know if the server actually accepted the connection is if the client actually tries to communicate with the server and checks if the responses time out. The queue handles the 3-way TCP handshake, so as far as the client knows, it really is connected. The server just doesn't know that yet until it calls `accept()`.